# How to select and insert In Microsoft Access database (accdb) in ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

Hey Everyone I am new to asp.net and I would like to select data from a database and store the data in a DataTable in VB not C#, but I just cant seem to understand how to connect. Can anyone help me try to connect to an access database? I am so lost and have been for days. if not its ok.

Thank you for reading.

Brent

```
Public Function CheckUser(ByVal p_strUserNAME As String, ByVal p_Password As String) As Boolean
    Dim blnAdminUser As Boolean = False

    Dim SQLQuery As String = "SELECT Username, Password FROM HomelessUsers WHERE Username = " & p_strUserNAME & " AND Password = " & p_Password

    Dim MDBConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\HomelessCapstone\HomelessCapstone\HomelessCapstone\APP_Data\Homeless.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(MDBConnectionString)

    cnn.Open()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQLQuery, cnn)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "HomelessUsers")
    cnn.Close()


    'Dim DatatableTest As DataTable = ds.Tables("HomelessUsers")
    'Dim Row As DataRow = Nothing
    'Dim Item(2) As String


    'For Each Row In DatatableTest.Rows
    'item()
    ' Next



    Return blnAdminUser
End Function
```

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: [Connection Strings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: ...and what error are you getting or what isnt working?

Comment: it says like its missing needed paramters?

Comment: "like"??? Is HomelessUsers a table of user names and passwords? You have a fairly useless query. You are asking for the very same things as in your WHERE clause...you shouldnt need to query for what you already know (just drop the WHERE and you'll get a list of all the users). Is the error coming from like the connection portion of from like the execution of the SQL query?  My Magic 8 ball says the SQL query - you need to add ticks to the string params: `WHERE Username = '" & p_strUserNAME & "' AND Password = '" & p_Password & "'"` but it is still like a silly query

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two ways you can go about it. 
One is to use ADO (access database objects) which has an intiutive wizard that will help you connect your access database to your program and set datasource for your controls,
Or you can use System.Data.OLEDb (I prefer this as it gives me more control over my system)

```
Dim accessconn As New  _
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & pathofAccessFile)
    Try
        accessconn.Open()
        MsgBox("Access succesfully connected")
        accessconn.Close()
        Return 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        accessconn.Close()
        MsgBox("There is something wrong with the path provided.")
    Return 1


    End Try
```

You will need an understanding of using OLEDb classes though, so here is something to help you out.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OleDb(v=vs.110).aspx

Take note of OLEDbCommand(Execute SQL strings), OLEDbDataAdapter(Translate data from DB to Datagridview) and OLEDbDataReader(I use this for selecting data from the Database).

Perhaps to help you more with understanding your problem, here is an example of how I use DataReader Class:

```
  Public Sub AccesstoGridd(ByVal utos As String, ByVal pathh As String, ByVal gridd As DataGridView, ByVal ngalan As String)
    Dim accessconn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & pathh)
    Try


        Dim sqlutos As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(utos, accessconn)
        Dim idcounter As Integer = 0

        accessconn.Open()
        Dim reader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        reader = sqlutos.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            idcounter = idcounter + 1
            gridd.Rows.Add(idcounter, reader(0), reader(1), reader(2), reader(3), reader(4), reader(5), ngalan)
        End While
        reader.Close()


        accessconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        accessconn.Close()
        MsgBox("There is something wrong with the Access file selected." & vbNewLine & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "MDB file unrecognized.")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: ok is there any way you could give me an example what goes in dataadapter and Datareader?

Comment: With the code you provided, you just didn't call the functions of the class so that your dataAdapter will work. Also, you didn't create a OLEDBCommand variable as well.
Look at my edit